# When to use deflate() of deflateroutputstream?

Tags: java, outputstream

I'm trying to learn how to use DeflaterOutputStream as something to kill time during my winter break. I'm confused because when I look at the documentation  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html, it says that `deflate()` is used to write a compressed data to OutputStream, while `write()` is to write data to the DeflaterOutputStream (compressed OutputStream) to be compressed.

However, I'm looking at sample codes on the internet, but none uses `deflate()` at all. All the code I've seen so far just `write()` to the DeflaterOutputStream without calling `deflate()`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13060441/12181863
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream
[image: Sample from geeksforgeeks]

I noticed that the code puts a FileOutputStream inside the DeflaterOutputStream, but how does it interact? Does it automatically call `deflate()` to send compressed data to FileOutputStream when data is written to DeflaterOutputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `protected`: It is intended for anything subclassing that stream, and you're not subclassing it, so as far as you are concerned, it is an implementation detail you cannot include in your reasoning and which isn't meant for you to invoke.

Unless, of course, you subclass it.

Which you could - it's sort of a toolkit for building LZ-based compression streams on top of. That's why both GZipOutputStream and ZipOutputStream extend it: Those are different containers that more or less use the same compression technology. And they *do* invoke that `deflate`. Unless you're developing your own LZ-based compression system or implementing a reader for an existing, non-zip, non-gz, non-deflater based compression format, this is not meant for you.

These kinds of outputstreams are called 'filterstreams': They do not themselves represent any resource, they wrap around one. They can wrap around any `OutputStream` (or any `InputStream`, the concept works on 'both sides' so to speak), and modify bytes in transit.

`var out = new DeflaterOutputStream(whatever)` creates a new deflater stream that will compress any data you send to it (via `out.write(stuff)`), and it will in turn take the compressed data and send it on to whatever. It does the job of:

1. take bytes (as per `out.write`), buffer as much as is needed to do the job:
2. ... of compressing this data.
3. Then process the compressed data, as it becomes compressed, by sending it to the wrapped outputstream (`whatever`, in this example), by calling its `write` method.

The basic usage is:

1. Create a resource, such as `Files.newOutputStream` or `someSocket.getOutputStream` or `httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` or `System.out` or anything else that produces a stream - it's a abstract concept for a reason: To make things flexible.
2. Wrap that resource into a `DeflaterOutputStream`
3. Write all your data to the deflateroutputstream. Forget about the original - you made it so you can pass it to DeflaterOutputStream, and that's where your interaction with the underlying stream ends.
4. Close the deflaterstream (which will end up closing the underlying stream as well).